Fetching data from Member(Contact) and Devotee(Devotee__C) objects and displaying in one data table. Member data displays but Devotees does not
Data is displayed when I query the Contact record but no data is displayed when I query some data from the Devotees table. Console.log is showing that it is fetching the Devotees data properly from the Apex method.
HTML
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contact Search">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <!-- Input Fields for Contact Name, Email, and Phone -->
            <lightning-input 
                label="Name" 
                value={contactName} 
                onchange={handleInputChange} 
                data-field="Name">
            </lightning-input>

            <lightning-input 
                label="Email" 
                value={contactEmail} 
                onchange={handleInputChange} 
                data-field="Email">
            </lightning-input>

            <lightning-input 
                label="Phone" 
                value={contactPhone} 
                onchange={handleInputChange} 
                data-field="Phone">
            </lightning-input>

            <!-- Search Button -->
            <lightning-button label="Search" onclick={handleSearch} class="slds-m-top_medium"></lightning-button>

            <!-- Datatable to display Member search results -->
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={contacts}
                columns={columns}
                class="slds-m-top_medium">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>

</template>

JS
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContacts'; // Apex method to search contacts
import getDevotees from '@salesforce/apex/DevoteeController.getDevotees'; // Apex method to search devotees

export default class ContactSearch extends LightningElement {
    // Track the user inputs for Name, Email, and Phone
    @track contactName = '';
    @track contactEmail = '';
    @track contactPhone = '';
    @track contacts = []; // Array to store the member search results
    @track devotees =[]; // Array to store the devotees search results
    @track errorMessage = ''; // Track any error messages

    // Columns for Member lightning-data table
    columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email' },
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' }
    ];
    // Columns for Devotee lightning-data table
    columns1 = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name__c' },
        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email__c' },
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone__c' }
    ];

    // Handle input change for Name, Email, and Phone
    handleInputChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.dataset.field;
        if (field === 'Name') {
            this.contactName = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'Email') {
            this.contactEmail = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'Phone') {
            this.contactPhone = event.target.value;
            // Remove brackets and dashes from the phone number
            this.contactPhone = this.contactPhone.replace(/[()\-\s]/g, '');
            // Output the cleaned phone number for debugging
            console.log(this.contactPhone);
        }
    }

    // Handle search button click
    handleSearch() {
        const inputArray = [
            { field: 'Name', value: this.contactName },
            { field: 'Email', value: this.contactEmail },
            { field: 'Phone', value: this.contactPhone }
        ];
        const inputArray2 = [
            { field: 'Name__c', value: this.contactName },
            { field: 'Email__c', value: this.contactEmail },
            { field: 'Phone__c', value: this.contactPhone }
        ];

        // Convert inputArray to JSON Stringify to send to Apex
        const searchInputs = JSON.stringify(inputArray);
       // const searchInputs2 = JSON.stringify(inputArray2);
        this.errorMessage = ''; // Clear previous error messages

        // First, try to get contacts
        getContacts({ searchInputs })
            .then(result => {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    this.contacts = result; // If contacts are found, set the result
                } else {
                    // If no contacts found, call getDevotees
                    getDevotees({ searchInputs })
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                            this.contacts = result; // Set devotees if found
                            // Display fresh data in the datatable
                            refreshApex(this.contacts);
                            console.log(this.contacts);
                        } else {
                            this.errorMessage = 'No records found in Contacts or Devotees.';
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error retrieving records:', error);
                        this.errorMessage = 'An error occurred while searching.';
                    });
                }
            })
            
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error retrieving records:', error);
                this.errorMessage = 'An error occurred while searching.';
            });
    }
}


ContactController.getContacts
public with sharing class ContactController {
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(String searchInputs) {
        // Deserialize the input JSON
       // List<Map<String, String>> searchParams = (List<Map<String, String>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(searchInputs);
        // Deserialize the JSON into a List of Objects
                    List<Object> searchParamsUntyped = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(searchInputs);

                    // Initialize the List<Map<String, String>> to hold the final result
                    List<Map<String, String>> searchParams = new List<Map<String, String>>();

                    // Iterate over the untyped list and cast each entry to Map<String, String>
                    for (Object obj : searchParamsUntyped) {
                        if (obj instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
                            Map<String, Object> mapItem = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
                            Map<String, String> stringMap = new Map<String, String>();

                            // Loop through each entry in the map and cast the values to String
                            for (String key : mapItem.keySet()) {
                                    stringMap.put(key, (String) mapItem.get(key));
                            }

                            searchParams.add(stringMap);  // Add the strongly-typed Map<String, String> to the final list
                        }
                    }

                    // Now searchParams is a List<Map<String, String>> with proper casting
                    System.debug(searchParams);

        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE ';
        List<String> filters = new List<String>();

        for (Map<String, String> param : searchParams) {
            if (param.get('value') != null && param.get('value') != '') {
                filters.add(param.get('field') + ' LIKE \'%' + param.get('value') + '%\'');
            }
        }

        if (filters.size() > 0) {
            query += String.join(filters,' AND ');
            System.debug(query);
        } else {
            query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM Contact';
        }

        return Database.query(query);
    }
}

DevoteeController.getDevotees
public with sharing class DevoteeController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<DCMSS_Devotee__c> getDevotees(String searchInputs2) {
        //Map<String, String> inputs = (Map<String, String>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(searchInputs);
        // Deserialize the JSON into a List of Objects
        List<Object> searchParamsUntyped = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(searchInputs2);

        // Initialize the List<Map<String, String>> to hold the final result
        List<Map<String, String>> searchParams = new List<Map<String, String>>();

        // Iterate over the untyped list and cast each entry to Map<String, String>
        for (Object obj : searchParamsUntyped) {
            if (obj instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
                Map<String, Object> mapItem = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
                Map<String, String> stringMap = new Map<String, String>();

                // Loop through each entry in the map and cast the values to String
                for (String key : mapItem.keySet()) {
                        stringMap.put(key, (String) mapItem.get(key));
                }

                searchParams.add(stringMap);  // Add the strongly-typed Map<String, String> to the final list
            }
        }

        // Now searchParams is a List<Map<String, String>> with proper casting
        System.debug(searchParams);

        String query = 'SELECT Id, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Email__c, Phone__c FROM DCMSS_Devotee__c WHERE ';
        List<String> filters = new List<String>();

        for (Map<String, String> param : searchParams) {
            if (param.get('value') != null && param.get('value') != '') {
                filters.add(param.get('field') + ' LIKE \'%' + param.get('value') + '%\'');
            }
        }

        if (filters.size() > 0) {
            query += String.join(filters,' AND ');
            System.debug(query);
        } else {
            query = 'SELECT Id, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Email__c, Phone__c FROM DCMSS_Devotee__c';
        }

        return Database.query(query);
    }
}


If you are getting the Devotee records. Then the reason why it is not displaying is because, of the columns attribute in your <lightning-datatable>
Currently, you are passing in columns to be in the format of:
columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' }
];

It seems for your Devotee records, the fieldName are meant to be Name__c, Email__c and Phone__c. If your fieldName does not match with the data you provide datatable will not show the data as it is null.
One way to fix this is by returning columns dynamically, if its Member or Devotee like this:
typeOfData = '';
get columns(){
    if(this.typeOfData === 'Devotee'){
        return [
            { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name__c' },
            { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email__c' },
            { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone__c' }
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
            { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email' },
            { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' }
        ]; 
    }
}

//getContacts method
getContacts({ searchInputs })
.then(result => {
    if (result.length > 0) {
        this.typeOfData = 'Contact'; //new
        this.contacts = result; // If contacts are found, set the result
    } else {
        // If no contacts found, call getDevotees
        getDevotees({ searchInputs })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                this.typeOfData = 'Devotee'; //new 
            }
        })
    }
})

